# Can't connect to pear.php.net

Tags: linux, php, pear

If I try anything with PEAR, I get:

```
# pear list-all
Connection to `pear.php.net:80' failed: Connection timed out
```

If I ping it, I get the following:

```
# ping pear.php.net
PING euk1.php.net (5.77.39.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

I've also tried host and dig on the URL:

```
# host pear.php.net
pear.php.net is an alias for euk1.php.net.
euk1.php.net has address 5.77.39.20
# dig pear.php.net

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> pear.php.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5866
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pear.php.net.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pear.php.net.           292     IN      CNAME   euk1.php.net.
euk1.php.net.           292     IN      A       5.77.39.20

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 85.119.80.232#53(85.119.80.232)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec  3 11:45:33 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65
```

If I use curl pear.php.net I get a connection timeout, but if I try curl www.google.co.uk I get a response. I'm not really sure about iptables, but have also documented the output from that:

```
# iptables -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Anyone have any ideas what to try or to look at to try and resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can ping this address without problem so maybe it's problem with firewall somewhere in your network or problem on internetwork connections. You can diagnose this problem using command

```
traceroute pear.php.net
```

or

```
mtr pear.php.net
```

Comment: thanks, it was the VPS provider's DNS that had issues so added Google's DNS to resolv.conf